# Autolayout constraint won't update for lovin or money

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a method in a custom class that sizes and constrains a custom UIView:

```
-(void) sizeAndConstrainHeaderView:(HeaderView *)headerView inView:(UIView *)view {

    CGFloat height;
    // code to calculate height is omitted.

    headerView.heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:headerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:height];

    headerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    if (!headerView.isConstrained) {
        [view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:headerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:0]];
        [view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:headerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:0]];
        [view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:headerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:view.frame.size.width]];
        [headerView addConstraint:headerView.heightConstraint];
        headerView.isConstrained = YES;
    }

    headerView.heightConstraint.constant = height;
    // trying everything here to get the constraint to update
    [headerView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [headerView layoutIfNeeded];
    [view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [view layoutIfNeeded];

    NSLog(@"height constraint constant: %f", headerView.heightConstraint.constant);

}
```

I call it like this in the view controller:

```
[customClass sizeAndConstrainHeaderView:_headerView inView:self.view];
```

Since this gets called several times (once before data is retrieved, once after), there is a flag for whether to add constraints. Then, regardless, the height constant is set to the calculated height. But no matter what I call, on the view or the custom view, the height of the view won't change, and I can't figure out why. The other constraints are working fine. The log shows the height changed. But the view doesn't reflect it. I know for sure because I debugged the view hierarchy and can see it did not update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said

> Since this gets called several times (once before data is retrieved, once after), there is a flag for whether to add constraints.

But your method does this on **every** call:

```
headerView.heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:headerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:height];
```

So on every call, you create a new constraint, store it in `headerView.heightConstraint`, and set the new constraint's constant.

However, you only install this new constraint in the first call to the method.

Perhaps you should only create the constraint on the first call:

```
-(void) sizeAndConstrainHeaderView:(HeaderView *)headerView inView:(UIView *)view {

    CGFloat height;
    // code to calculate height is omitted.

    if (!headerView.isConstrained) {
        headerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        [view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:headerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:0]];
        [view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:headerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:0]];
        [view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:headerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:view.frame.size.width]];

        headerView.heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:headerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:height];

        [headerView addConstraint:headerView.heightConstraint];
        headerView.isConstrained = YES;
    }

    headerView.heightConstraint.constant = height;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be many issues here, because Autolayout is a complex thing.  But I'd take issue straight away with your initial declaration of what the height constraint is.  You declare the CGFloat height - but you dont give it a value.  Then you set that as the constant on the height constraint property of headerView.  So it seems like you are giving 0 as a constant, probably rendering the constraint useless.

Are you using a nib or storyboard for the view?  If so, you can drag the constraint you want to affect directly into your view class with an IBOutlet.  This is the most common way to programmatically change a constraint constant at run-time.  Just drag it in as a class property, and change the .constant value of it like that.

Another issue could be that the other constraints at play in the superview are clashing with this one, and Autolayout has decided to prioritise another one over this one.  If there are clashes with the constraints, you will get big fat log messages about it, so keep an eye out for those.

Heres how I do programmatic constraints usually, works fine :

```
NSMutableArray *constraints = [NSMutableArray array];
NSString *verticalConstraint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|-%i-[headerView(%i)]-%i-|", topBuffer, height, bottomBuffer];
NSString *horizontalConstraint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-%i-[headerView(%i)]-%i-", leading, width, trailing];
[constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:verticalConstraint options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(headerView)]];
[constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:horizontalConstraint options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(headerView)]];
[self addConstraints:constraints];
```

Comment: My code comment says, "code to calculate height is omitted.". I assure you it is not zero. I also said, "The log shows the height changed". 

Also, I'm not getting any log messages warning about unsatisfiable constraints.

Comment: Ok sorry missed that.  Is there a reason why you dont just drag in the height constraint from the nib / storyboard and change it directly?  You can be sure then you are affecting the correct constraint.  Or are you doing this all programmatically?

Comment: Yea all programmatically, as you can see, the height constraint is created in code. I don't know why doing it in IB would make it work any better...

Comment: Adjusted my comment above to add how I usually do programmatic constraints.  Ive used this many many times, always does the trick.

Comment: On doing it in IB or not - fact is Autolayout is hard, even when you have been doing it for years.  Theres always a new challenge with it and things can always go wrong.  IB is by far the better way of managing it because you get immediate feedback if things are wrong.  Doing it programmatically is just risky unless you know it really well.  So if you can, do it in IB (even if your view is very simple), then you can check that the constraints work right in the first place - and you also know that the height constant you are dragging across via IBOutlet is actually working in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can see where making constraints in IB can be helpful, though in my case I couldn't do it in IB.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I use these calls, I never pass nil as the toItem parameter. Passing nil means that the constraint isn't relative to anything, which makes any height/width calculation meaningless. Caveat: I don't usually use the constraintWithItem call, its much easier to use the visualFormat api when possible.